# LZO compression of OpenVPN insecure?

Tags: encryption, tls, openvpn

I [read about](https://www.howsmyssl.com/) the [CRIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME) attack against TLS, that it's avoidable by turning off the TLS compression in the browser. Does this also apply to OpenVPNs `comp-lzo` option, so that it should get turned off?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the previous answer, didn't find it when looking for OpenVPN in specific.